# Percentage of rows calculation in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with cid, distance. Distance values spread from 0.0000125 to 20000.00. Approximately my 80% data is between 0 -10 distance units. So I  have made the distance into the bin by 10 to easy representation. here is my table looks like below. 
[image]

Please help how to get the 3rd row with %age of cids based on the count and total counts of it.